# React-Native Formik and axios post route response not being made to MongoDB express backend

Tags: mongodb, react-native, post, axios, formik

Below is my code for my sign up form. I am using Formik and axios to make a post request to the backend which is using express and MongoDB. Once I filled out my sign up form and hit the signup button I receive the values that I typed in and also the console.log message "its working!". However, I don't get the console.log message 'post request made' so it's not posting to the backend. I have used postman to hardcode the initial values to the localhost:3001/register route and it posted to the backend in Mongodb atlas. Does anyone see anything wrong with my axios code?

I have recently received a new error of request failed with status code 400 when I changed my route to http://localhost:3001/register.

````
                initialValues={{ 
                    name: "",
                    email: "",
                    password: "", 
                    passwordConfirmation: "",
                    birthday: "",
                }}    
                onSubmit={values => {
                    console.log(values)
                    console.log('its working!')
                    const url = 'localhost:3001/register';
                    axios
                        .post(url, values)
                        .then(response => {
                            console.log('post request made!')
                            if (response.data.status) {
                                console.log(response);
                                }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {console.log(error)})
                        }}
            >
               {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                    <View>
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Enter your name'
                            onChangeText={handleChange('name')}
                            value={values.name}
                        />
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Enter your email'
                            onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
                            value={values.email}
                        />
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Enter your password'
                            onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                            value={values.password}
                        />
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Confirm your password'
                            onChangeText={handleChange('passwordConfirmation')}
                            value={values.passwordConfirmation}
                        />
                        <TextInput 
                            style={styles.input}
                            placeholder='Enter your birthday'
                            onChangeText={handleChange('birthday')}
                            value={values.birthday}
                        />
                        <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                            <View style={styles.checkboxContainer}>
                                <CheckBox
                                    value={isSelected}
                                    onValueChange={setSelection}
                                    style={styles.checkbox} 
                                    boxType="square"
                                    onFillColor="#AB73F7"
                                    onTintColor="#AB73F7"
                                    onCheckColor="#fff"
                                />
                            </View>
                            <View style={styles.termsContainer}>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>I agree to <Text
                                    style={styles.privacyLink}
                                    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://google.com')}>Terms
                                </Text>
                                    <Text> and </Text>
                                    <Text
                                    style={styles.privacyLink}
                                    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://gmail.com')}>
                                    Privacy
                                    </Text>
                                </Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.btnContainer}>
                            <Button
                                style={styles.btn}
                                title="Sign Up"
                                color="#fff"
                                accessibilityLabel="Sign Up"
                                onPress={handleSubmit}
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            </Formik> ```
````

Comment: 400 is a bad request. That means the UI is hitting the API but it does not like `values` sent to it. Make sure the request body is what the API expects. If that doesn't work you will need to provide code examples from the API.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using localhost:3000/register use your system's IP address
ex: http:://ip_address:3000/register

Comment: also convert your values to FormData

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30581336)